# Import a txt file to an 2D array and remove special characters in each line

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I've tried many options to import a text file with this format:

headerline

headerline

headerline

[DD/MM/YY - HH:MM:SS:MS] +00975 +026.98 -0000.6 -0000.5     N2

[DD/MM/YY - HH:MM:SS:MS] +00975 +026.98 -0000.6 -0000.5     N2

[DD/MM/YY - HH:MM:SS:MS] +00974 +026.98 -0000.6 -0000.5     N2 ...

The target is to create a 2D array that contains each value from a line as an individual element, with the lines arranged as rows.
So far, I only managed to get one entire line as an element in the array using numpy.genfromtxt:

`data = numpy.genfromtxt("test.txt", skip_header=3, delimiter=" ")`

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- For a simple and Pythonic way you can do the following:

```
    # Start reading the entire file using readlines() method.
    with open('test.txt') as my_file:
        my_array = my_file.readlines()
 
    # After that skip empty lines iterating over my_rray:
    my_array = [l.split(" ") for l in my_array if l != "\n"]

    # Finally create a numpy array from your python list:
    data = np.asarray(my_array)
```

2- On the other hand, you can use `genfromtxt` method for a more elegant solution and solve it in one line:

```
    data = numpy.genfromtxt('test.txt', dtype=str, delimiter=" ")
```

Note that:

- I'm telling numpy to treat values as strings
- Numpy automatically filter empty rows in your file

More info about genfromtxt [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html)

Result for your first two lines should be looks similar to the following:

```
array([['[DD/MM/YY', '-', 'HH:MM:SS:MS]', '+00975', '+026.98', '-0000.6',
        '-0000.5', 'N2\n'],
       ['[DD/MM/YY', '-', 'HH:MM:SS:MS]', '+00975', '+026.98', '-0000.6',
        '-0000.5', 'N2\n']], dtype='<U12')
```

I hope I have understood well what you want to do and that my answer would be useful!

Comment: Hi Emiliano,  thanks for your answer! Unfortunately, I still have the problem that each line is imported as a single element (there's no comma separation between the values)

Comment: array([['[08/10/21 - 14:43:45:921] +00975 +026.98 -0000.6 -0000.5     N2 '],
       ['[08/10/21 - 14:43:45:923] +00975 +026.98 -0000.6 -0000.5     N2 '],
       ['[08/10/21 - 14:43:45:925] +00974 +026.98 -0000.6 -0000.5     N2 '],
       ...,
       ['[08/10/21 - 16:00:05:435] +00975 +026.78 +0005.1 +0004.8     N2 '],
       ['[08/10/21 - 16:00:05:482] +00975 +026.78 +0005.0 +0004.8     N2 '],
       ['[08/10/21 - 16:00:05:515] +00975 +026.78 +0005.1 +0004.8     N2 ']],
      dtype='<U72')

Comment: Okey I got it! I added an extra step to split each row by " " on the pure python approach (l.split(" ")) this should do the job! Also, the second approach should be working as you expect! Notice that in the first one you have more flexibility to make changes in the way you are importing the rows, in case you are not so familiar with numpy

Comment: Just one more issue: Some lines contain more elements than most of the lines. Thus I get this error message: "Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray." Is there a way to skip lines?
Also, each line is formatted as a list and I get this output:

array([list(['[08/10/21', '-', '14:43:45:921]', '+00975', '+026.98', '-0000.6', '-0000.5', '', '', '', '', 'N2', '\n']), and so on with "dtype=object"